# Does afterPropertiesSet guarantee inner properties are initialized as well?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following classes:

```
public class C implements InitializingBean {


    @Autowired
    private B b;

    @override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
          b.doSomething();
    }
}

public class b {


    @Autowired
    private A a;

    public void doSomething() {
            a.foo()
    }
}
```

It seems like I'm getting a Null exception in `b.doSomething` since `a` isn't initialized yet.
Does it guarantee that afterPropertiesSet is called the properties in the inner class are initialized as well?

Thanks,
Nir.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer yes.

As you can see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpcdR.png

PostProcessors like afterPropertiesSet are called after populateProperties, and therefore those fields are no longer null.

If something is not getting autowired it is because Spring doesnt know about that class - you need to mark it for spring with for example `@Component`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've verified that my inner class is marked as component. For some reason it's still not initialized.